# Generate mesh from 8 sides textures

Tags: mesh, texturing

I have some sprites that have 8 angles and would like to know if it would be possible to create a mesh from those 8 images with blender? The images look something like this:

[image: Textures]

I remember once asking on Blender discord and someone mentioned a tool within blender that could generate something decent to work with as we have 8 angles but can't remember the name of the tool anymore.